# How to fill `EditText` items with different colors?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-edittext

Could I fill different color in an EditText items like this?

[image]

Sure, I'm able to use two `EditText` but I curious that it is able to use an `EditText`.

Comment: good question, but more clarity required.

Comment: @GokulSreenivasan Thank you for comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, you have to use the `Spannable` class.

```
final String yourText = "Your text to be filled";
final int length_you_want = 5;
Spannable modifiedText = new SpannableString(yourText);
modifiedText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.green)), 0, length_you_want, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textView.setText(modifiedText);
```

Comment: Thank u for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yon can do it differently if you have two different text to color and later combine into one;

```
 public String getColoredString(String pname) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    Spannable wordToSpan = new SpannableString(pname);
    wordToSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, pname.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return wordToSpan.toString();
}
```

pass the string into the method and use it where you want.

```
textview.settext(getColoredString("your text1")+getColoredString("your text2));
```